# Azure Lighthouse - Get the region for subscription level deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I want to onboard Azure Subscription into my tenant. For that, I created an ARM template with `subscriptionDeploymentSchema`. If I open this template from the portal, I get prompted to choose a region. Is there any way I get the value of that built-in field into my template and use it?
[image]
I want to display value of the "Region" field (built-in) in the "Region Name", which is my field. Is that possible?
I know for the resource group level deployment I can use `resourceGroup().location`, but that does not work here.

Part of my template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "mspOfferName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify a unique name for your offer"
            }
        },
        "mspOfferDescription": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the Managed Service Provider offering"
            }
        },
        "regionName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Should have value of the 'Region' built-in field"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        ...
        {
            "name": "myNestedTemplate",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
            "location": "<i-want-to-use-value-from-the-built-in-field>", // <-- I WANT TO USE REGION FROM THE BUILT-IN FIELD HERE
            ...
        }
    ],
...
}
```

Is that even possible? Or should I create a field for user to provide a region? The second option does not make any sens, as you would be prompted to provide two locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`deployment().location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-deployment#return-value) to get the value of the `Region` field.

Comment: Also, if you set the defaultValue to ```[deployment().location]``` that's what will appear in the text box, i.e. it will *not* be EastUS in the portal UI.  If you really want to customize the UX you have to supply your own uiDefinition.json file - or, you can just remove the regionName parameter from the template and use ```[deployment().location]``` for the value of the location property.